# Python: Can't import networkx module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make some graphs with Python. I am trying to import this library called networkx. I ran the command `pip install networkx` in my Python folder. Tried to import the library but error messages came along. I tried to run `pip install networkx` again and these messages came along:

```
requirement already satistfied.... (use -upgrade to upgrade)...
```

It should have been installed but when I run `file networkx *` i get syntax error and for `import networkx` I get `no module named networkx`. What is wrong?

I want to ask is the the python directory the place to install libraries, what are good libraries for drawing graphs and do I have to add the libraries to the PATH, when I add them.

Comment: Please share the code you got so far. Shorten your code if necessary in order to provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you using Python2 or Python3? Which system/OS are you working on?

Comment: I am using python 3.6 and the only thing I have tried is to import the library itself

Comment: Could you please check if there is a `pip3` command available in your terminal/command line (or short: do have installed Python2 and Python3 in parallel on your system)? If so, you installed `networkx` for Python2 and not for Python3. Additionally, please provide the snippet of your py-file and how you tried to run it since this is a bit confusing based on the descriptions given in your question.

Comment: in cmd pip3 is not recognized. I had python 2.7 but I deleted it, I tried to run the `import networkx` with the python.exe file and in a seperate file both give the same result. How can I check if I have python 2.7 and how to delete it permanantly ?

Comment: `pip freeze` should give you a list with installed packages (containing packages installed through pip to be precise). Please check if the desired module is listed. After that you should type `python --version` in your terminal in order to check which version the `python` command is running. If this is version 2 try `python3 --version` instead. After that is clarified, you should create a file named e.g. `test.py` containing `import networkx` and execute it on termial via `python test.py` (or `python3` for Python3). This makes sure that python iteself and the package is installed correctly

Comment: pip has installed networkx and I am running python3, this is not the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117847/discussion-between-albert-and-murloc).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For me networkx was not installed when I first called it.
When I installed it somehow it wasn't updated to be available in the script.

So I made a new file, dragged and dropped the whole code into there and magically it worked.

Not sure what happened, but I'm using Visual Studio Code, maybe it's an issue with the interpreter...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).